# "Be on night shift," "be on a night shift," "be on the night shift"?

Tags: articles

Could you tell me which of the following sentences is the most natural and correct?

> Last night I was **on night shift**, so I'll just catch up on some sleep.
>
> Last night I was **on a night shift**, so I'll just catch up on some sleep.
>
> Last night I was **on the night shift**, so I'll just catch up on some
> sleep.

Comment: null set, a and the is addressed in many answers.

Comment: [Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+on+night+shift%2Cwas+on+a+night+shift%2Cwas+on+the+night+shift&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) a usage chart showing that all three versions are perfectly common. And I can't really see any scope for different *meanings*, so you can just use whichever of ***a, the***, or ***null*** you like best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say *"was on **a** night shift"* (version of the statement) is the least natural of the three. Personally, I wouldn't consider the first two common usage. But if you used the *"on the night shift"* version, you can expect people to understand that. But the other two not so much.

> [night shift](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/night-shift) (Longman Dictionary)
>
> 1. a period of time at night when people regularly work, especially in a factory
>    **on the night shift**
>    *She’s on the night shift this week.*

I'd use *"worked the night shift"* instead.

[image]

Comment: All three are idiomatic in different contexts. ngrams will not cut it here.